# How best to use D3 without duplicating lots of code?

Tags: graph, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, toolkit

I'm getting into data visualisation, and have been a bit surprised to discover how verbose D3 is. The end results can be fantastic: very specialised visualisations that react nicely to changes in data. But mostly the visualisations that I see people do are cookie-cutter clones from the [D3 Gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery).

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to create similar examples other than by simply copying all the code and changing bits? Are there no libraries, or layers built on top of D3? The [list of plugins](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins) in the D3 Github is pretty uninspiring.

I guess I'm also questioning for what purposes D3 is best suited, and when it's not appropriate. Something like a spectrum from:

1. Standard bar chart: use jqPlot or similar
2. Non-standard but not novel, dynamic visualisations (ie, copying anything in the Gallery): ???
3. Novel visualisations that are dynamic or interactive: use D3

Is there a better approach for duplicating an existing style of visualisation than simply copying all the code? Is there some other library that's more customisable than say jqPlot, but doesn't require the explicit "here's how you draw a bar chart" approach of D3?

(Sorry for the poorly worded question - having trouble articulating what my exact issue is.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a general question, but let me have a go at answering it. I think the closest to what you're asking for would be a [reusable chart](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/), which aims to provide the code for a particular kind of chart in a way that you don't need to write a lot of code to use it ("a lot of code" is subjective of course). Many of the D3 plugins use this pattern, so I think this is what you're looking for.

Even if you have a reusable chart, there's a certain amount of boilerplate code you *have* to write to tie everything together. For completely data-driven graphs, have a look at [Vega](https://github.com/trifacta/vega/wiki/Tutorial). Some of the verbosity of D3 also comes from the fact that the attribute names are usually human-readable (i.e. quite long) and there's usually a number of attributes to be set for a given visualisation. In many cases, you could set this in CSS as well.

As for the question when to use D3, that's entirely up to you. I would use D3 for basically everything, but then again I'm far more familiar with it than anything else. I certainly wouldn't say that you shouldn't use it for a standard bar chart. Even though the code may be a bit longer than in another framework, you have lots of options when it comes to customising it. This actually comes up a lot here, when people use one of the higher-level libraries based on D3 and find they can't customise it the way they want.

Finally, here are a few things you might be interested in. There's [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/), which is one of the higher-level libraries I've mentioned. There's also [d3charts](https://github.com/idan/d3charts), which has a similar purpose. Both of these reduce the amount of code you have to write for simple charts. There're more out there as well, and of course you can always wrap your favourite chart in a reusable layout.

Comment: Awesome response to my rambling question. Ok, Mike B's blog post is 2 years old, and without comments it's hard to tell whether it went anywhere. d3charts looks dead 2 years ago. NVD3 looks pretty healthy. Vega isn't so interesting to me (and IMHO combining data and presentation parameters into the same data structure is Just Wrong). The verbosity of D3 isn't so much the problem as the lack of encapsulated knowledge about types of charts.

Comment: Hmm, there's also D3-chart: http://misoproject.com/d3-chart/examples.html Looks like early days there though.

Comment: And two useful essays on the topic, leading to d3.chart: http://weblog.bocoup.com/reusability-with-d3/ and http://weblog.bocoup.com/introducing-d3-chart/